# Having difficulty working with pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference

I having some issue when it comes to initializing pointers.

```
void findMM (int *PMM, int *theG)
{
        // code  I haven't written yet. It will essentially take two variables from   //theG and store it in MM  
}

int main() 
{ 
    int size;
    int MM [2] = {1000, 0}; 
    int *theG = NULL; 
    cout << "\nPlease insert size of array:" << endl; 
    cin >> size; 
    theG = new int [size];  
    findMM(&MM, &theG); //Get error with &MM  
    delete [] theG;     
    return 0; 
}
```

The complier says that argument of type `int (*)[2]` is incompatible with parameter of type `int **` So obviously that I have issue with the code in particular my (reference?) of array MM. Or perhaps there is other obvious faults that I am missing?

Edit attempt 2

```
void findMM (int *PMM, int *theG)
{
        PMM [1] = 5; 
        theG [0] = 7; 
}

int main() 
{ 
    int size;
    int MM [2] = {1000, 0}; 
    int *theG = NULL; 
    cout << "\nPlease insert size of array:" << endl; 
    cin >> size; 
    theG = new int [size];  
    findMM(MM, theG);
    cout << MM [1] << endl << theG[0];    
    delete [] theG;     
    return 0; 
}
```

The output would be 5 and 7 correct?

Comment: An array is already a pointer. Remove the & from &MM in call to findMM.

Comment: @TheSavage That is not true!

Comment: Can you give me a more detailed answer cause that just confused me...

Comment: @TheSavage Arrays are not pointers. Arrays _decay_ to a pointer to the first element of the array.

Comment: Do you intend to use `findMM` in C program as well? If not, why are you using raw arrays instead of stl containers? How can you tell the size of `theG` inside `findMM` if you don't pass it (the size) as a parameter?

Comment: Yea I mean use findMM but haven't written the code yet as was problems passing the data around. So if I passed size how would I implement that in context to the pointer? in other words I don't understand what you mean...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `MM` is an array, `&MM` is a pointer to an array (that's the type `int (*)[2]` that you see in the error). Instead, you seem to want to pass a pointer to the first element of the array. There are two ways to do that. Firstly, you can explicitly get the first element and then take the address of it: `&MM[0]`. Secondly, you can rely on array-to-pointer conversion to do it for you and just pass `MM`. Array-to-pointer conversion converts an array to a pointer to its first element.

Comment: But if I wanted to pass the entire array because ultimately at the end of the function I want change both MM [0] and MM [1] to different values so would I have to pass both address?

Comment: @user3207442 No, you access the elements of the array using `operator[]` just like a normal array.

Comment: @user3207442 No. Do you know that `a[x]` is equivalent to `*(a + x)`? So if `a` is a pointer to the first element in the array, `a[1]` will do `*(a + 1)` which gives you the second element in the array. Magic!

Comment: Okay let me rephrase this to ensure I understand. If I say put PMM [0] = 5 in the function and then put a cout statement in the main ie cout << MM [0] it will equal 5 correct? ignoring the obvious syntax errors in this comment.

Comment: @user3207442 Correct. And if you do `PMM[1] = 5;` in the function, and then `cout << MM[1];`, you will get 5 again.

Comment: Would mind checking my 2nd attempt above to ensure I am writing this correctly. Sorry, I just want make sure I am understanding this correctly.

Comment: @user3207442 Sorry, noticed a mistake. `theG` is already a pointer so you don't need to take the address of it to pass it to `findMM` (since it expects a pointer too).

Comment: @JosephMansfield I updated that in the edit 2 version

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has already been answered but I believe I can contribute to the asker's understanding.

Let's start with the basics:

```
void main()
{
    int a = 2; // a is an int
    cout << a << endl; // print 2

    int *b; // b is a pointer-to-int
    b = &a; // store the address of a in b
    cout << *b << endl;// print the value that b points to, which is 2

    int my_array = new int[3]; // allocate an array with 3 integers
    my_array[0] = 50; // store 50 in the first element of the array
    my_array[1] = 51; // store 51 in the second element of the array
    my_array[2] = 52; // store 52 in the third element of the array
    cout << c[0] << endl; // print 50

    some_function(my_array, 3); // explained below
}
```

Now let's see how to pass arrays into functions. Assume we want to have a function called `some_function` that receives an array.

```
void some_function(int *some_array, int size_of_the_array)
{
    // use the array however you like here
}
```

The function `some_function` receives a pointer to an `int` (also known as "pointer-to-int"). The name of an array is always the address of its first element, so if a function expects a pointer to an `int` and you give it the name of an array of `int`s, you are actually giving it the address of the first element in the array (this is just C++ syntax rules). So the function now has the address of the first element in the array, it can do stuff like `*some_array` to access the first element in the array, but what if it wants to access the other elements? It adds 1 to the pointer it already has and then applies the * operator to it: `*(some_array + 1)`. Let's say an `int` is 4 bytes, if you add 1 to a pointer-to-int, the result of this addition is a new pointer that points to a location in memory 4 bytes ahead, so `*(some_array + 93)` is the value in the 94th element of the array `some_array` (array elements are stored sequentially in memory). A shorthand notation for this is `some_array[93]`. So if you have `int *some_array = new int[100];`, then `some_array` is a pointer and `some_array[93]` is the same as `*(some_array + 93)`, which is the 94th element in the array.

The address itself though is not enough, you also need to know the number of entries in the array so that you don't try to access an element past the end of the array. In this example, assume that `some_function` simply prints the contents of the array, so if you don't provide 3 as the second argument to the function then it will have no way of knowing when to stop adding 1 to the pointer it received in the first argument. Beware, however, that by passing an array to a function this way, you are not passing the function a copy of the array, you are simply telling it where to find its contents in memory.